# File stuck in pending until WiFi is turned on

Tags: java, android, android-service, android-permissions, android-download-manager

I'm using Download Manager to download a file Ton an Android 10 device that is connected to a private APN on cellular network which leads to a private server.
*The server is not reachable from regular internet.

The request looks like this:

```
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI);
request.setDestinationUri(Uri.fromFile(getFile()));
request.setAllowedOverMetered(true);
request.setAllowedOverRoaming(true);
request.setTitle(mContext.getString(R.string.title));
request.setDescription(mName);
```

Saving the file into `File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Download");`

Manifest is configured with necessary permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

When pushing a file through the Download Manager code, I can see the file is on queue, with status: 1 ("PENDING"). When I turn on WiFi, the download notification appears and the file fails to download (as it is not reachable from the internet).
**There is no error in Logcat logs.**

Tests I've done:

1. Checked downloading the file directly from a browser and it works.
2. Tried downloading a file from the internet using the same code, both over WiFi and regular Cellular and it works.
3. Installed the same code on Android 12 and Android 13 device - same thing.

How can I make Download Manager work without the internet connectivity it probably requires?

Comment: Interesting. Please add a question to your post.

Answer (score 0):

Download request fails with a reason code for the error. The reason is stored in `DownloadManager.COLUMN_REASON` and if it is http error in then it is stored like a non 200 integer, in your case it has to be `PAUSED_WAITING_FOR_NETWORK` code.

Comment: Nope, reason is 0. This hawthorns because Android sees there is no Internet connention. If an internet connection becomes available, the download starts.